# Select folder, file and transfer to a user defined function for plotting the file data

Tags: python-3.x, database, file, data-analysis, directory-structure

Want to create a web page based app using python.
Requirement:

1. Initially it should ask for log in username and password.
2. As soon as the login is successful, it should ask for folder and file selection.
3. Once the file is selected, it should plot the data from the file based

Can anyone please suggest what all python libraries best suits for all the above operations?

I use Pandas, Numpy for data preparation and Plotly for plotting the data, is there any better python library for data preparation and plotting?
Please let me know your feedback.